# setting dgrid allowSelectAll to true is not working

Tags: dojo

I have an empty grid, with the columns defined as below:

```
              var json = { };
              json.col1 =  { label: 'Select', selector: 'checkbox' };
              json.bndryName = "Boundary Name";
              return json;
```

The boundary grid is initialized as below and the data/collection is loaded on a button click,and when I set allowSelectAll:true, I donot see the the header column rendered with a checkbox to select All. Please advise.

```
           this._bndryGrid  =   new (declare([OnDemandGrid, Selection,Selector,ColumnResizer]))({

                                    selectionMode: "multiple",
                                    columns: columns,
                                    class:'grid',
                                    loadingMessage: "Loading data...",
                                    noDataMessage: "No results found."

                                }, this.ap);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you've provided enough to go on here (and your grid doesn't even include `allowSelectAll: true`), but here is an [example that works](http://jsfiddle.net/qwxs3onx/):

```
require({
    packages: [
        {
            name: 'dgrid',
            location: '//cdn.rawgit.com/SitePen/dgrid/v1.0.0'
        },
        {
            name: 'dstore',
            location: '//cdn.rawgit.com/SitePen/dstore/v1.1.1'
        }
    ]
}, [
    'dojo/_base/declare',
    'dgrid/OnDemandGrid',
    'dgrid/Selection',
    'dgrid/Selector',
    'dstore/Memory',
    'dojo/domReady!'
], function(declare, OnDemandGrid, Selection, Selector, Memory) {
    var data = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Peter' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Paul' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Mary' }
    ];
    var store = new Memory({ data: data });
    var options = {
        allowSelectAll: true,
        collection: store,
        columns: [
            { field: 'id',  label: '', selector: 'checkbox' },
            { field: 'name', label: 'Name' }
        ]
    };

    new (declare([ OnDemandGrid, Selection, Selector ]))(options, 'gridcontainer');
});
```

Comment: Hi ken - there are two stages with my dgrid functionality. Initializing the dgrid layout and second stage-setting the collection or store in my grid . The code I provided above, is my init code. When I click a button, I set the collection property and set the property "allowSelectAll:true" . when I set the property "allowselectall to true" during initialization , without setting the store, I get an error "Cannot read property 'getIdentity' of null". When i set the store and allowselectall : true during the loading stage. I don't see any checkbox appearing. Please advise how to go about this.